# pandas create a noon datetime for a datetime column

Tags: pandas, date, datetime

I have a datetime64[ns] column in pandas like this:

```
2013-10-01 14:32:00
```

I want to create another column, replacing the time part of the datetime with noon (keeping the date part) , so I have the noon time for all the datetimes in the dataframe:

```
2013-10-01 12:00:00
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?
thanks

Comment: What is output if `2013-10-01 04:32:00` ?

Comment: Hi - that will be noon of that datepart - so 2013-10-01 12:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandaspydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by days and then add `12 hour`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['2013-10-01 14:32:00','2013-10-01 04:32:00'])})

df['date1'] = df['date'].dt.floor('D') + pd.Timedelta(12, unit='h')
```

Or:

```
df['date1'] = df['date'].dt.floor('D') + pd.offsets.DateOffset(hours=12)
```

---

```
print (df)
                 date               date1
0 2013-10-01 14:32:00 2013-10-01 12:00:00
1 2013-10-01 04:32:00 2013-10-01 12:00:00
```